# New windows from the dock in Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, dock

I am using Gnome Shell on Ubuntu 11.10, and I frequently use workspaces, as the shell encourages to do. My only complaint is that it is slow to place different windows of the same program in different workspaces.

What I would like to do: click on an empty workspace, click on the Nautilus icon in the dock and browse to the correct folder. Then click on another empty workspace, click on the Nautilus icon and so on.

This does not work: the second time I open Nautilus, the dock lets me switch to the previous instance, which is almost never what I want. So I have to click on the Nautilus icon, open a new window, place it on a different desktop, switch to that folder and finally browse to the correct folder.

> Is there a way to simplify this flow?

It would be even better if I was able to link a specific folder from the dock, or better yet to have something similar to a Unity lens, where I can choose between the most used folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try one of the following in the dash:

[ctrl]+left mouse opens another instance of a program in the current workspace.

Middle mouse or mouse wheel click opens another instance of a program in a new workspace.

Drag and drop the program launcher (the one you would click on) to one of the workspaces on the right. The Program will be executed on that workspace.

I guess the best for you is to just middle-click the nautilus launcher a few times.